# Spring MapsId not resolving target entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have such a case where I need to have internally `many-to-one` using hibernate proxies and only id externally, here using `MapsId`. The issue appears when I try to save something, because the target entity is not fetched, when I set the value only on the id.

Let's take an example: I have an `Account` table and `DeviceConfig` table. Inside the DeviceConfig's class definition, I add `account` in a `many-to-one` relation and `accountId` in relation with `@MapsId`.
Now when creating, I always set a value to `accountId`, but never the value is picked up, and the backend throws an SQL error, because the field cannot be null.

```java
@Table(name = "djl_device_config")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DeviceConfig extends CoreEntity {

    ...

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("accountId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private Account account;

    @Column(name = "account_id", insertable = false, updatable = true, nullable = true)
    private UUID accountId;
}
```

So I suppose this is a config error on my side, but I've been reading the JPA for these three days and I still don't know what's wrong or what I should do to achieve the behaviour I expect.

That for any help you'll provide.

Comment: Remove the `accountId` field and ditch the `@MapsId`. You are making things overly complex.

Comment: The thing is I'm using the `accountId` field at the frontend side

Comment: Just provide a `getAccountId` on the `DeviceConfig` that does `account.getId()`. Instead of trying to double map it. Or create a DTO to use on the frontend instead of trying to shoehorn everything into a single object.

Comment: Remove `@MapsId` and put `@JoinColumn(name = "account_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)` and `@Column(name="account_id", insertable=true,updatable=true)`.

Comment: It doesn't work the way Iexpect it to, when I use `insertable=true,updatable=true` because I cannot update the field.

Comment: If I use a getter like `getAccountId`, it will increasse the overall complexity, because now I should need todo the same for every classes and adapt also for setters.